# How to create a EditText common for all activities with its contents?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want a EditText such that it should be visible to all activities & if I change its contents in any activity, they should reflect in every activity.Please give me solution...!!!

Comment: Use fragments, and in the activity make the `EditText` static

Comment: Are you using any button to save the text that is being typed in the Edittext?

Comment: DO NOT MAKE VIEWS STATIC! You risk a memory leak. Create a shared preference and store the value for the edit text in there. Then in every activty, fragment whatsoever read and write to that preference.

Comment: I'm using dropdown to set text

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a fragment , fragments are reusable , and can be attached to multiple activities , there is a single xml and java file for a fragment, when you make changes of EditText in these files , changes will be made in all of your activities , So make a fragment and attach it to all of your Activities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use all activities, you can create a static variable

```
public class Utils {
    public static String myString;
}
```

And before you start another activity, you can set the variable

```
Utils.myString = editText.getText().toString();
```

Then onResume of each activity, you can get the variable and set it to EditText

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (editText!= null) {
                        editText.setText(Utils.myString);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

But i recommend that you should use fragment is this case. It's easier.

Answer (score 0):

Reuse the same fragment across the different activities.
The assumption here is that you want the edit text to be shown in activity 1 and 2.
Activity1 will be called before Activity2.
the layout of both activity1 and activity2 have a framelayout of id *holder*

**Activity1**

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity{

public static Fragment editTextFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_group);

        ...

        editTextFragment = new EditTextFragment();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.holder, editTextFragment);
        ft.commit()

}



}
```

**Activity2**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_group);
        ...
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.holder, Activity1.editTextFragment);
        ft.commit()
}

}
```

**EditTextFragment.java**

```
public class EditTextFragment extends Fragment {
    public testFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edittext, container, false);
    }

}
```

**layout/fragment_edittext.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.editTextFragment">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```